# Implementing an ADT linked list from scratch

Tags: java, linked-list, addition

I've got a class project where I have to build an ADT-based linked list from scratch (meaning I can't use any standard Java ADTs) and then use that to sort a bunch of `State` objects (that each also contain a linked list of `Cities`) alphabetically. The backbone of the code is, obviously, the handmade `OrderedLinkedList` class, and I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to implement, speficially, a `findOrAdd` method that iterates through the list and, if the argument passed is not already in the list, adds it in the appropriate spot (and returns the element if it's already there). Most of the things I've read about implementing linked lists don't deal in ADTs and so it's difficult to convert that in my mind and still wrap my head around it. My (admittedly incomplete) OLL code and its accompanying iterator:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class OrderedLinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Iterable<E> 
{
    private E first;
    private E next;
    private E last;
    private E current;
    private E temp;
    private int size;

    public OrderedLinkedList() 
    {
        this.first = null;
        this.next = null;
        this.last = null;
        this.current = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public E findOrAdd(E element)
    {
        E returnVal = null;
        Iterator<E> listIter = this.iterator();

        if (this.first == null)
        {
            this.first = element;
            this.size++;
        }

        else 
            for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++)
                {
                    if (listIter.next().compareTo(element) == 1 && listIter.hasNext() == false)
                    {
                        temp = this.first;
                        this.first = element;
                        this.next = temp;
                        this.size++;
                    }   
                    else if (listIter.next().compareTo(element) == 1 && listIter.hasNext() == true)
                        continue;
                    else if (listIter.next().compareTo(element) == 0)
                        returnVal = element;
                    else if (listIter.next().compareTo(element) == -1)
                    {
                        temp = this.next;
                        this.next = element;                        
                    }               
                }

        return returnVal;
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator()
    {
        return new OrdListIterator<E>();
    }

    private class OrdListIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> 
    {
        private E nextNode;

        public OrdListIterator()
        {
            //maybe something needed here
        }

        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            return (next != null);
        }

        public E next()
        {       
            return (E) next;
        }

        public E first()
        {
            return (E) first;
        }

        public void remove()
        {
            //implement later
        }
    }
}
```

I've got compareTo() methods in the `State` and `City` classes that override the usual method but still function the same way. Where am I going wrong in `findOrAdd`? *How* am I going wrong? I'm not looking for a full correction of the code or anything; I'm about 99% sure everything under that `else` block is abysmal. I just need a push in the right direction: someplace to get a foothold. I'd hugely appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you issue may lie in the fact that you are calling `listIter.next()` for each condition may mean that you are pushing the iterator through at each check. Possibly you should store this at the beginning of the loop then use the single object in your comparisons...

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. I haven't quite gotten to the point of using the provided testing code, so I wasn't sure if that would be a problem, but it definitely wasn't sitting well with me. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Did that address the issue you were having or were you looking for something further?

Comment: So looking at it in light of your suggestion (I added a `E current = listIter.next();` declaration at the top of the loop), I actually need to switch what the -1 and 1 `if`s do, right? So if the argument comes after the `current`, the loop continues after another `listIter.next()` call, but if the argument comes before the `current` then it slots into place there and the node markers are shifted accordingly.

Comment: Yes I believe that is correct from what I could determine. Your first `if` statement if looking for when it is less than the first node which occurs when `current.compareTo(element)` returns a negative number.
Also something that I found that helps is rather than use `current.compareTo(element) == 1` use `current.compareTo(element) > 0` simply because of the contract [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html] for the Comparable interface as it only requires it to be positive further it can be easier to read, `current.compareTo(element)>0` reads current > element